# Is there a way in word VBA to find an embedded picture (inlineShape) extension (jpeg, png, emf...)?

Tags: vba, ms-word, file-extension

I am trying to determine in a docx document the extension of the embedded images.
This open xml document may have been generated by another user, with Microsoft Word or OpenOffice.
Images have been embedded through the ribbon, or drag and drop, and they can be inlineShape (mose of the time), or Shape.
I need to access the extension, because the document is then (not in my jurisdiction) parsed and converted to pdf, and some image extension are not compatible with the processe (namely emf of wmf).

These images may not have names, nor alternativeText properties.
The linkFormat property is not available either, since they are embedded.
By looking through the ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML string, I can know if there are such images. But then, I can not link them to the corresponding shape in the document to identify which image will be problematic.
Since they are embedded, the folder media in the docx zip contains the image, and they are linked to ids in the document through the document.xml.rels, e.g.

```
<Relationship Target="media/image1.emf" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Id="rId8"/>
```

Now I can find in the document.xml where is used that rId8 :

```
<w:drawing>
  <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="59736095" wp14:editId="3A4D29FE">
    <wp:extent cx="1286510" cy="712470"/>
    <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="8890" b="0"/>
    <wp:docPr id="2" name="Picture 2"/>
    <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
      <a:graphicFrameLocks noChangeAspect="1"/>
    </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
    <a:graphic>
      <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
        <pic:pic>
          <pic:nvPicPr>
            <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="Picture 2"/>
            <pic:cNvPicPr>
              <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="1" noChangeArrowheads="1"/>
            </pic:cNvPicPr>
          </pic:nvPicPr>
          <pic:blipFill>
            <a:blip r:embed="rId8" cstate="print">
              <a:extLst>
                <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                  <a14:useLocalDpi val="0"/>
                </a:ext>
              </a:extLst>
            </a:blip>
            <a:srcRect/>
            <a:stretch>
              <a:fillRect/>
            </a:stretch>
          </pic:blipFill>
          <pic:spPr bwMode="auto">
          </pic:spPr>
        </pic:pic>
      </a:graphicData>
    </a:graphic>
  </wp:inline>
</w:drawing>
```

From there on I am stuck! What to do with any of this data ?
The parent node of the drawing is a paragraph, with an id

```
w14:paraId="78D01A35"
```

but this is the only instance of the id in the ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML string.

I would like to have pointers as to where I can look.
From what I understand, when Word parses the docx and builds the object model, it converts the relationship links into inlineShape with anchors at the good location.
But it somehow loses all reference to the picture name or location within the docx zip.

P.S. : I need to find a solution in vba word

Comment: There's no "media" folder in the doc zip structure?

Comment: There is. That's what stated in the relationship xml. I guess I could go and open the media to have a visual idea of which image in the doc is wrong, but then it would not be automatic anymore. I need an automati solution in my word vba macro.

Comment: I was thinking you could use code to look in the media folder and see the extensions...

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I do, by looking in the ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML string I get to know the content of the media folder without unzipping

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. The `rId` is the "link" between the location of the image in the document and the actual graphics file.

All the inforamtion in document.xml is "formatting", so what the file extension (image type) will never be stored there, only in the media relationship.

In document.xml this is where to find the `rId` in the XML you show

```
  <pic:blipFill>
        <a:blip r:embed="rId8" cstate="print">
```

What you need to pick up is `blip` and then `embed`. This information may help you http://officeopenxml.com/drwPic-ImageData.php

You can try using RegEx or some kind of string parsing to pick this up. Or it could be done using MSXML and XML "parsing". What will work will depend on how closely all these things follow a recognizable pattern, and how much time/effort it would take you to learn how to use the XML object model.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into it.
I do search through the xml with vba InStr function. What I don't manage, is to find the place in the "document", get to select the image in the selection object for instance.
My work around is to look in the xml before the image for a specific pattern : `[a specific markup]`. And than I can identify the image inform the user of which image is not in the good format.
From your answer, I get that you can `embed` the image. What does that mean? How do I achieve that ?
Your link allowed me to understand what means the `a:blip` line, thanks a lot.